# Java Import From External Jar Default Package

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to use a method that is located inside of a package in an external jar that i have loaded.

The problem is, this method relies on a class that is in the same jar but it is in the Default Package so i cannot import it into my project.

Is there a way to do this?

Using: Eclipse

Comment: You need to be more clear, post code, mention how your running the application (command line, eclipse ,...)

Comment: Sorry, i thought i mentioned that i was running in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import the default package, since it has no importable path. You have to create a package and place the class in that.

Edit:
**project << build path << add library << add external jars** << add to build path

Comment: How do i get the class from the external jar though?

Answer (score 0):

If the class is already in the jar file and the jar file is on your classpath (in eclipse add the jar to build path, in command line add jar using -cp option) it should work fine no imports for the dependency class needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The class is called in.class and if i just do import in; it comes up with an error.